# Using Ubuntu Cloud as cloud storage for all Ubuntu installations

Tags: cloud, storage

Is it possible to use the Ubuntu Server Cloud as a storage solution for all of my Ubuntu installations. As in, the same way the Ubuntu One service works, where it is synced with all of my computers if I choose that as an

Answer (score 1):

As I understand you need a clustered file system which is available to all machines in a Linux based infrastructure.

I suggest you to have a look at [Lustre](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lustre_%28file_system%29). This is almost exactly what you are looking for except that it does not sync the data locally.